# Mobile safari crashing while capturing photo using input type = file

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari

I am using input type file for launching the camera in iOS . The following line of code I am using :

```
 <input type="file" name="select a Picture"/>
```

When I press the button it shows two option i.e. 1) Take a Picture  2. Choose from the gallery 
If I select option Choose from the gallery then it launches the native gallery when I select the picture from the gallery then I can see it in the preview , so choose from gallery is working fine .

But the problem is with taking picture using camera . When I Press the take picture it launches the camera but it after capturing the photo it directly goes back to the safari . And there is pop of which shows the following error:

```
A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded
```

so how to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Try to reset network setting and clear the history and Cache of Safari.. I hope work for u.

Comment: yeah , its working now , I did nothing , but still its working now :)

Comment: I've filed the following bug report (radar) with Apple for this issue: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5006458726907904

Answer (score 9):

In my case, adding a name="" attribute fixed the problem. I had:

```
<input id="uploadPhotoInput" type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*">
```

and it crashed every time. Changing it to:

```
<input id="uploadPhotoInput" name="uploadPhotoInput" type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*">
```

seems to have done the trick. I have no idea why, since I wasn't submitting it in a form or anything, but there it is.

Comment: The trick works for me too and I have no idea either. Maybe a bug o iOS?

Comment: Confirming that this is still the case with modern devices and that this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Also remove any onchange="xxxxxxx" from your input tag (if you have any) since for some reason is causing problems in iOS8.